# How to color a part of a polygon of a card with R?

Tags: r, polygon

I have the map below and I would like to color only the southern border of the map.

`library(rgdal)`

`library(prettymapr)`

`x=readOGR(file.choose())`

`plot(x)`

`addnortharrow()`

`addscalebar()`

`box()`

[image]

Comment: You would probably have to generate a new line/polygon feature and plot it in another color.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it better would be asked on gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: plot(x,border=c("red")) , but it colors all the polygon.